# dc.js composite chart errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I am working with DC.js and crossfilter. There are two js files in my project. chart1.js is for visualisation#1 and chart2.js is for visualisation#2. I am trying to use a composite chart to combine three bar charts in chart2.js. However, there are two errors in the console. I have no idea why these errors happen.

One error is `Uncaught Mandatory attribute chart.dimension is missing on chart[#chart-bar-lifecycleCost].`

Another one is `Uncaught TypeError: allCostChart.width(...).height(...).dimension(...).group(...).x(...).elasticY(...).centerBar is not a function.`

It seems that chart1.js can run smoothly, but chart2.js has the errors mentioned above. Here is part of chart2.js:

```
var lifecycleCostChart = dc.barChart('#chart-bar-lifecycleCost'),
    plannedCostChart = dc.barChart('#chart-bar-plannedCost'),
    projectedCostChart = dc.barChart('#chart-bar-projectedCost'),
    allCostChart = dc.compositeChart('#chart-composite-allCost'),
    agencyRowChart = dc.rowChart('#chart-agency-row'),
    dataTable2;



d3.csv('/data/Projects_CW1.csv', function (error, data) {

if (error) {
    console.log(error);
}


data.forEach(function (d) {

    d.lifecycleCost = +d["Lifecycle_Cost"];
    d.plannedCost = +d["Planned_Cost"];
    d.projectedCost = +d["Projected_Actual_Cost"];
    d.agnecyName = d["Agency_Name"];

});


var ndx = crossfilter(data);


var lifecycleCostDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d["Lifecycle_Cost"];
    }),

    plannedCostDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d["Planned_Cost"];
    }),
    projectedCostDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d["Projected_Actual_Cost"];
    }),

    agencyNameDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d["Agency_Name"]
    }),

    allDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d;
    });


var all = ndx.groupAll();

var plannedCostGroup = agencyNameDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.plannedCost;
    }),
    projectedCostGroup = agencyNameDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.projectedCost;
    }),
    lifecycleCostGroup = agencyNameDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.lifecycleCost;
    }),
    agencyNameGroup = agencyNameDim.group().reduceCount();

allCostChart
    .width(500)
    .height(320)
    .dimension(agencyNameDim)
    .group(agencyNameGroup)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .elasticY(true)
    .centerBar(true)
    .barPadding(5)
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel('Count')
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .compose([
        dc.barChart(allCostChart)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(100)
        .colors('red')
        .dimension(lifecycleCostDim)
        .group(lifecycleCostGroup)
        ,
        dc.barChart(allCostChart)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(100)
        .colors('blue')
        .dimension(plannedCostDim)
        .group(plannedCostGroup),
        dc.barChart(allCostChart)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(100)
        .colors('blue')
        .dimension(projectedCostDim)
        .group(projectedCostGroup)])
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .render();
```

Here is part of the screenshot of csv file. I want to list these three variances as bars in a composite chart according to different agency names.

[image: part of screenshot of csv file]

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to create separate divs or chart objects for the the different parts of the composite chart. So your `lifecycleCostChart` and its siblings are not needed. Since you never initialize them, dc.js complains that they are missing attributes.
2. `centerBar` is a method of the bar chart, not the composite chart. You should apply it to the child charts, not the composite itself.